# NoMethodError: undefined method `stub' for ModuleX:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, integration-testing, mocha.js

Using Mocha, I am trying to mock a controller method that calls a module method. 
This is for an integration test.

Example:

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
  def method1
    response = Module1.method2(...
```

My steps so far:

- Added mocha to gemfile
- Added `require 'mocha/mini_test'` to the very bottom of my
  test_helper.rb
- Tried this code in my integration test before sending a post to my controller:

  `Module1.stub(:method2).returns(:true)
  post "controller/method1"`
- And got this error:

  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'stub' for Module1:Module`

Is it possible to stub method2?

EDIT: So the main fix is that the method is 'stubs' not 'stub'. I'm still having trouble mocking this dang Module though.

EDIT: Rails and MiniTest just call the module method even after I've stubbed it. Is it possible that Rails is overwriting my stub?

```
class Test < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

test "test do

Module1.stubs(:method2).returns(:true)
post "controller/method1"
```

This test leads to error inside method2 bc no parameters were passed in.  The test is behaving as if the method was not stubbed.

Answer (score 5):

for me this was caused by not adding `require 'minitest/mock'` to my `test_helper.rb`

Comment: I wouldn't add it in test_helper.rb but only in the specific test, where stubing and mocking is used.

Answer (score 2):

try `.stubs` with an s.

The `stub`notation is to build a stub you'lle use later on.
Add an s when you stub a method directly on something.

Comment: So, your suggestion has solved my first problem; however, I am still unable to mock this method. Rails and MiniTest just go and call the module method even after I've stubbed it. Is it possible that Rails is overwriting my stub?

Answer (score 1):

regarding your test you may want a

```
Module1.expects(:method2)
```

but the stub should work anyway. Rails would not overrite your stub, maybe you test_helper does, but i'm quite sure it is more a syntax thing.

Paste your real code and test because here right know it's kind of difficult and can be anything... a callback preveting the method to be called, the test syntax, ...